# Question laptop vs server for http web site and database

Tags: laptop, server, web-server

i have an 15 years old laptop that i am using to run
xampp ( http php website database) and a java program and windows 10 os
the website is only being used by max of 3-5 users self use / apps that run ones a day to get data from the server and the java app that runs ever 60 sec (not heavy work)
i wanted to buy new laptop but was thinking maybe i should be buying a server but i not sure
so should i get a server ? what are the + and - to laptop vs server
i just dont know how many users/apps(backbone) will req me to move to server?
like :
cost?
up time ( am gona have to buy ups)?
os?
and all the other specs of laptop vs server ? cpu ram networking
any recommended servers ?

hope this is the right place to ask this am not really sure
thx in adv :)

Comment: are you using that laptop as a web server 24/7? if so I recommend removing the battery if you haven't already. Keeping it plugged in that long can cause overcharging and could be a fire hazard.

Answer (score 0):

When architecting your software solution you usually would want to try and run a load test to see if your response times are acceptable. It sounds like you're not running into any significant issues b/c you didn't mention anything specific.

In your use case I find it hard to justify choosing, purchasing, and then maintaining the hardware for a full power on-premise server designed for concurrent processing. Also without knowing your database design or RAM capacity, I can only guess that your database is able to fit in memory and would be fairly quick.

The item I would be the most concerned about a 15 year old laptop is disaster recovery and backup. What happens if your laptop fails?

An option to explore is using Cloud services like Amazon AWS or Azure? Here it is very easy to have more than one worker process to handle requests, and if your userbase or db complexity were to suddenly increase you could easily scale up your services at a click of a button. Depending on what server you buy you could possibly end up paying more on your power bill than one of these options.

---

I would either keep your current option or look into trying out some Cloud services. I know that Amazon AWS gives you some free credit, I'm less sure about Azure as I think you may need Visual Studio PRO subscription or higher to get credit. You really should look into some disaster recovery scenarios regardless.

Comment: do u have any exp with aws azure google cloud ? how much will it cost to run apache and mysql server ? for small business

Comment: How much it will cost would depend on the tier of server you buy. I'd imagine you'd want to buy the minimum tier for your workload. You'll have to explore the options. Amazon [AWS actually has a free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).